# A command to download latest PHPmyadmin release?

Tags: apt, phpmyadmin, wget, automation, curl

I ask since I'm considering a `apt-get install` alternative.

I can do the following curl to donwload the latest PHPmyadmin release:

```
curl https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.6.5.2/phpMyAdmin-4.6.5.2-all-languages.zip
```

Is there a command that downloads the latest release **automatically** with either curl or wget, or something different?

Comment: It probably needs some parsing of the webpage https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ to fetch the first one in the list :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, you can look at [phpMyAdmin website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/about-website/#syndicate) for them.

The easiest way is:

```
curl --location https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
```

Or with wget:

```
wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
```

However that will always download latest version even if it has not changed, so you might rather monitor https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/version.txt for changes...

Comment: Thanks! I looked up today in the downloads page and didn't found the above link. I suggest adding it specifically to there as in a "apt-get install alternatives" chapter. Thanks again!!!

Comment: It will be definitely listed more prominently, see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12869

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest (in terms of scripting complexity) is to checkout the git sources and use the STABLE branch. This is updated with each release, so you're automatically tracking the latest with that branch. You can easily script a `git pull` and merge.

The only minor setback will be that phpMyAdmin now uses Composer to handle dependencies with library files, so you'll need that installed and you should add `composer install` and/or `composer update` to your script after the git portion. I'm not a Composer wizard but think 'install' is appropriate here; YMMV.

A robust shell script for this might be 10-15 lines long, though I'd probably jam it in to a single line of crontab (or equivalent).

If you prefer to use the official distribution (which packages library files, removing your dependency on Composer), there are a number of helper files published by phpMyAdmin that can help you. They're currently documented [here on the phpMyAdmin website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/about-website/#syndicate); in your case I imagine you would want to parse either https://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/version.txt or https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/list.txt which contain enough information to determine whether you need to download an update and the URL to the latest version. Since you've mentioned that you prefer a solution that is not dependent on Composer, this is almost certainly your best choice. I'd write a small script that saves the date or version that's currently installed, then occasionally compare it to the versions listed on one of those files, and then download the new file as needed (along with uncompressing and adding `config.inc.php`).

Hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your time and investing in this for the community. I personally don't use composer (at least for the time being). You mention pulling it from git branch, it is interesting, I believe I should learn basic usage of the `git` utility for this.